# Transações de mySQL no React com Knex.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript, knex.js

Vou colocar a rota abaixo que está dando problema, mas já adianto algo: sem o transaction funciona tudo legal, no front, no back e no banco, mas não tenho a segurança do transaction, e quando adiciono ele dá o seguinte erro: Error: Transaction query already complete, run with DEBUG=knex:tx for more info

Código: server.put("/moverCard", async (req: Request, res: Response) => { const db = knex({ client: 'mysql', connection: { //dados confidenciais } })

type taskType = {
id: number, titulo: string, desc: string
}

type objType = {
titleColumn: string,
Tasks: taskType[],
idColumn: number
}

async function arrayRetorno(): Promise{

```
let arrayRetorno: objType[] = []

const arrColumns = await db('titulocolunas').where({email}).select()
if(arrColumns.length > 0){
    arrColumns.forEach(async (item, index) => {
        let idColumn = item.id
        let obj: objType = {titleColumn: item.tituloColumn, Tasks: [], idColumn}
        let arrCards = await db('cards').where({id_column: idColumn, email}).select().orderBy('idxCard', 'asc')
        if(arrCards.length > 0){
            arrCards.forEach((elem, idx) => {
                obj.Tasks.push({id: elem.id_card, titulo: elem.tituloCard, desc: elem.descricao})
                console.log(obj)
            })
        }
        arrayRetorno.push(obj)
        if(arrColumns.length == index + 1){
            res.json(arrayRetorno)
            console.log("era pra vir primeiro")
        }
    //Pq aqui fora o arrayRetorno se torna vazio?
    console.log("era pra vir por último")
    })
}else{
    res.json(arrayRetorno)
}
```

}

type bodyType = {
email: string,
idSourceColumn: number,
idDestColumn: number,
sourceIdx: number,
destIdx: number
}

const {email, idSourceColumn, idDestColumn, sourceIdx, destIdx}: bodyType = req.body

try{
let arrMovedCard = await db('cards').where({email, id_column: idSourceColumn, idxCard: sourceIdx}).select()

```
await db.transaction(async trx => {
    let isSameColumn: boolean = false
    if(idDestColumn == idSourceColumn){
        isSameColumn = true
    }



    if(!isSameColumn){

            //Deletando o card da coluna fonte, a gente colocou o delete primeiro pq senao tem a duplicidade de chave primária
            let respDelCard = await trx('cards').where({email, id_column: idSourceColumn, idxCard: sourceIdx}).del()
            //Atualizando os indexes da coluna destino (Esse tem que vir antes de add o card na coluna destino pq senao vc tbm vai adicionar um no valor do index do card adicionado e vc nao quer isso, ai da merda)
            let arrSumIdx = await trx('cards').where({email, id_column: idDestColumn}).andWhere(function(){this.where('idxCard', '>=', destIdx)}).select()
            if(arrSumIdx.length > 0){
                arrSumIdx.forEach(async (item) => {
                    let respSum = await trx('cards').where({email, id_card: item.id_card}).update({idxCard: item.idxCard + 1})
                }) 
            }
            //Adicionando o card na coluna destino
            let arrAddCard = await trx('cards').insert([{tituloCard: arrMovedCard[0].tituloCard, descricao: arrMovedCard[0].descricao, id_column: idDestColumn, id_card: arrMovedCard[0].id_card, email: arrMovedCard[0].email, idxCard: destIdx}])
            //Atualizando os indexes da coluna fonte
            let arrSubIdx = await trx('cards').where({email, id_column: idSourceColumn}).andWhere(function(){this.where('idxCard', '>', sourceIdx)}).select()
           if(arrSubIdx.length > 0){
            arrSubIdx.forEach(async (item) => {
                let respSub = await trx('cards').where({email, id_card: item.id_card}).update({idxCard: item.idxCard - 1})
            })
           }

    }else{
        let subindo = destIdx < sourceIdx
        if(subindo){

                console.log('subindo')
                //Deletando o card da coluna fonte, a gente colocou o delete primeiro pq senao tem a duplicidade de chave primária
                let respDelCard = await trx('cards').where({email, id_column: idSourceColumn, idxCard: sourceIdx}).del()
                //Atualizando os indexes da coluna destino (Esse tem que vir antes de add o card na coluna destino pq senao vc tbm vai adicionar um no valor do index do card adicionado e vc nao quer isso, ai da merda)
                let arrSumIdx = await trx('cards').where({email, id_column: idSourceColumn}).andWhere(function(){this.where('idxCard', '<', sourceIdx)}).andWhere(function(){this.where('idxCard', '>=', destIdx)})
                arrSumIdx.forEach(async (item) => {
                    let respSum = await trx('cards').where({id_card: item.id_card, email}).update({idxCard: item.idxCard + 1})
                })
                //Adicionando o card na coluna destino
                let arrAddCard = await trx('cards').insert([{tituloCard: arrMovedCard[0].tituloCard, descricao: arrMovedCard[0].descricao, id_column: idDestColumn, id_card: arrMovedCard[0].id_card, email: arrMovedCard[0].email, idxCard: destIdx}])

        }else{

                console.log('descendo')
                //Deletando o card da coluna fonte, a gente colocou o delete primeiro pq senao tem a duplicidade de chave primária
                let respDelCard = await trx('cards').where({email, id_column: idSourceColumn, idxCard: sourceIdx}).del()
                //Atualizando os indexes da coluna destino (Esse tem que vir antes de add o card na coluna destino pq senao vc tbm vai adicionar um no valor do index do card adicionado e vc nao quer isso, ai da merda)
                let arrSubIdx = await trx('cards').where({email, id_column: idSourceColumn}).andWhere(function(){this.where('idxCard', '>', sourceIdx)}).andWhere(function(){this.where('idxCard', '<=', destIdx)})
                arrSubIdx.forEach(async (item) => {
                    let respSum = await trx('cards').where({id_card: item.id_card, email}).update({idxCard: item.idxCard - 1})
                })
                //Adicionando o card na coluna destino
                let arrAddCard = await trx('cards').insert([{tituloCard: arrMovedCard[0].tituloCard, descricao: arrMovedCard[0].descricao, id_column: idDestColumn, id_card: arrMovedCard[0].id_card, email: arrMovedCard[0].email, idxCard: destIdx}])

        }
    }


})


arrayRetorno()
```

}catch(err){
res.json(["erro"])
}

})

Lembrando: o código é até "grande", mas o problema, acredito eu está na aplicação da transaction. Acho que estou retornando o "commit" mais de uma vez ou está acontecendo algum loop infinito, esses são meus palpites, mas não estou conseguindo ver aonde, alguém pode me dar uma ajuda por favor?

Comment: [Esta pergunta já foi feita antes](/q/591061/3635). Queira seguir as orientações dadas na outra conta, para melhorar a pergunta original. Para evitar duplicação de orientações, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas pode ser utilizado na outra postagem se necessário (após restauração).